# how build templates with JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

i'm new in this web site,i'm software student and developer. My problem is how to extend the default GUIs, with custom funcionality

if i extend base JFrame ,  the  button actionListener doesn't response to event in the derived JFrame, but it responds to the super classes's Jframe event.

Thanks for reading and wait for help you !

Comment: If you have code that is suspect, please post it - attempt to isolate the problem into a small subset of your overall code.  See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: its hard understanding your question. Do you mean your ActionListener is not working when you extend a class that extends JFrame?

Comment: i don´t know if create interface or abstrac class or symple herency becouse i have one class "A", after i want the other class B  is equal   to A in visual interface form  but your funcionality and logical change for each class

Comment: Think about `PropertyChangeListeners` and/or using data models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment below I modified my example such that it hopefully answers your question.

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyJFrame myFrameHello = new MyJFrame("Hello", 100, 100);
        MyJFrame myFrameGoodBye = new MyJFrame("Good Bye", 100, 250);
        myFrameHello.setVisible(true);
        myFrameGoodBye.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
        public MyJFrame(String labelStr, int x, int y) {
            this.labelStr = labelStr;
            setDefaultCloseOperation(MyJFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            label = new JLabel(" ");
            getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
            button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
            getContentPane().add(button);
            setBounds(x, y, 0, 0);
            pack();
        }
        private JLabel label;
        private String labelStr;
        private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(labelStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe is a solution but i´m not explainning very well , i comment my problem again.
Supose , you have a windows (JFrame ) with 3 buttons and 2 labels , if you press 1 Jbutton , one jlabel show "hello".Now i want other windows with 3 buttons and 2 labels too, but if you press 1 Jbutton , one labels mustn´t show "hello" now show "Bye"

Comment: I modified my example to hopefully better answer your question.

Comment: thanks Howard for your help, i can resolve my problem and implements in the source code